# Why are infinite sums so much harder to calculate than the associated infinite integral?

Tags: calculus, soft-question, summation, big-picture

It seems that with continuous functions, we have in calculus an apparatus for "short cutting" an infinite sum. However, when we move to the discrete case, it seems that we don't have the equivalent theoretical machinery.

What is it about sums that makes them so much more intractable than their associated integrals? In other words, why isn't there a fundamental theorem of infinite sums like there is for calculus?

Comment: Hmm, the infinite sum $\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k = 1/(1-x) $ is an example for a "simple-to-compute" summation... And - what is simpler: the series  $1-2+3-4+5... =1/4$ or its integral-analogue? (I don't know the answer myself at the moment)

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Thanks for the example. I didn't mean that ALL infinite sums are impossible, but simply that if a given infinite integral is convergent and can be solved for the limit, the associated infinite sum, which will also be convergent, will be much harder to calculate.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms actually, I'd be interested in seeing the integral analogue of 1-2+3-4 etc as well

Comment: Yes the example (and possibly others) may sharpen the focus on the problem. (I've thought about a similar question some time ago but did not arrive at a conclusion then)

Comment: The integral-analogue for the alternating Dirichlet-series should somehow be derived from the bernoulli-polynomials?

Comment: Well the curve for the quadratics is smooth and also that of its integral. However, the curve of the partial sums of the series has the form of a staircase, just edgy; so the partial sums of the series might be seen somehow like piecewise integration. In such a case I would intuitively think that summation is more difficult. However, there is sometimes a telescoping effect which might simplify the expression for a series.

Comment: Hmm, that's all what I could contribute at the moment. Possibly it would be better to have the valueable/constructive aspects from my multiple comments compressed and filtered out and then delete that whole "chat"-like conversation... (I'm stepping out now, I've just a difficult matter to solve...)

Comment: [Summation by parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts) is the equivalent of integration by parts, and alternating series of the form $\displaystyle\sum_a^b(-1)^nf(n)$ have $\displaystyle\int_a^bf(x)\cos(\pi x)dx$ as their continuous counterpart.

Comment: @Lucian thanks..I've never seen those before. Are they part of a general theory of summation? For example, is there a relation between a difference equation and it's associated summation? I'd guess it would telescope and hence the fist and last terms define the sum. Is there a more sophisticated version of this that related the summands to the sum like the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: Are you referring to something like [discrete calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference) or the [Norlund-Rice integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norlund-Rice_integral) ? Anyway, the main idea is that in very many cases, infinite series are nothing else than that which is obtained by expanding the integrand into its own Taylor/binomial/hypergeometric, etc. series, and then switching the order of summation and integration.

Comment: @Lucian that is EXACTLY what I was referring to...but didn't know about this area. So we can see via discrete calculus why some series are analytically solvable...they can be represented as a discrete integral of a difference equation that happens to have an analytic solution. Very cool. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible alternative to calculus is considering measure theory. I realize this might be outside of the scope of the question, but measure theory allows us to discuss usual integrals and sums to be one in the same.

Comment: Yes, but how does this explain why some infinite sums lack a closed form while the associated integral does?

Comment: @Eupraxis1981 fair point - I was addressing the comment "when we move to the discrete case, it seems that we don't have the equivalent theoretical machinery". As for actual computations/calculations measure theory isn't necessarily the best...

Comment: @Eupraxis1981 glad to help!